# IPython on Emacs 24.2 doesn't work

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I'm a beginner in emacs and I'm trying to extend so it acts like a comfortable python IDE. Trouble is I can't seem to integrate Ipython to emacs. I'm running emacs 24.2 with Ipython 0.13.2 on Xubuntu 13.04.

I tried adding this to my .emacs file:

```
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
 python-shell-interpreter-args ""
 python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-completion-setup-code
   "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
 python-shell-completion-module-string-code
   "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
 python-shell-completion-string-code
   "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
```

But running python console from emacs (Python > Start Interpreter) just brings "Inferior Python Mode". I also tried "emacs-ipython-notebook" but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for...

Thanks!

Comment: With python-mode.el you should not need any of this configuration stuff `https://launchpad.net/python-mode` IPython-notebook is a different thing build upon IPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs 24.3 comes with a different python.el than 24.2. Your install points at symbols of 24.3, 24.2 python.el will ignore this.